# 404 error when trying to redirect with flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to modify this code so that I can pass bids to payfor_day. The redirect works fine when it isn't there, but gives a 404 when I try to add it.

For comparison:

```
return redirect(url_for('pos.payfor_day', memberid=result['memberid'], asat=result['arrival']))

@pos.route('/pos_display/payfor_day/<int:memberid>/<asat>', methods = ['GET'])
@access_group('POS')
def payfor_day(memberid, asat):



return redirect(url_for('pos.payfor_day', memberid=result['memberid'], asat=result['arrival'], bids = bids))

@pos.route('/pos_display/payfor_day/<int:memberid>/<asat>/<bids>', methods = ['GET'])
@access_group('POS')
def payfor_day(memberid, asat, bids):
```

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: your returns are outside the function?

Comment: Those returns are at the end of a separate function in another file

Comment: Can you please make this valid syntax in your MCVE because I keep getting tied in circles trying to understand your comparison

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. The reason it worked when I tried it without using the bids variable was because I was testing it by refreshing the page. As this change modifies what the URL in the browser will be, the two snippets of code belong to two different URLs, thus the 404 error when the old URL doesn't exist anymore.